# Multiclass AUC score higher than binary

Tags: classification, random-forest, multiclass-classification

I just built a random forest classifier and wondered about the results.

I have 4 classes: A, B, C and control. When I compare A vs control, B vs control, C vs control I get a lower average AUC score (0.8) compared to a multiclass approach with all 4 classes (0.85).

Would one expect this result and when yes why?

I would appreciate any help!

Comment: Could you elaborate on how the scores are produced?:  is the average 0.8 a flat average, or weighted?  How is the latter score produced?

Comment: The average 0.8 is a flat average of every binary comparison and calculated with sklearn's roc_auc_score. The average score of the multiclass is also flat average and is produced with the package Yellowbrick. The weighted average would acutally be 0.9.